# The audio keeps stopping on MPMoviePlayerController Audio streaming

Tags: ios, objective-c, stream, mpmovieplayercontroller, audio-streaming

Im using `MPMoviePlayerController` to stream audio from a server, but after playing the audio for more than two minutes, the audio starts to stop and resume alot, im streaming more than one file one after one, so because of the interruption, some of the audio files are being skipped with those two console messages:

```
 Took background task assertion (38) for playback stall

 Ending background task assertion (38) for playback stall
```

I'm losing a lot of tracks because of this error.
for the first while, i thought that was a memory issue, but the console shows that each time a loose a track, it print those messages,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your network connectivity and the stream encoding.

This console output pretty much says exactly what your problem is; the stream dries out of content and could not keep up playing without interruption.

Either your network connection is unstable or the content is encoded in bandwidths that are far too high for your network connection.

For clarification; even if your local internet peering is offering high bandwidths, you should still check the bandwidths of the entire route. For example, you could try to download the streamed files via your browser for testing the throughput.

Comment: I have an internet connection with 24Mp speed

Comment: When saying that you should check your connectivity, I actually mean that you should check the entire route to the server providing the content in question. Rest assured the problem is somewhere within encoding and transport, not within the client side code.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying it on a simulator or a device? It may be a simulator issue.

Also, on device, try streaming through multiple networks, e.g., LTE, wifi, etc., see if there is any difference

Comment: I have the same problem but only on cellular and not on wifi.

Comment: @RawMean Your cellular bandwidth might not be high enough. Typically, wifi achieves higher bandwidth.

Comment: That's what I thought but SpeedTest tells me that I have 30Mbps downlink and 10Mbps uplink.  Even stranger: this stalling problem started yesterday.  I used my radio app on my way to work in the car everyday for the past year.  I tried it on another iPhone and the same stalling problem shows up on it as well.  very puzzled.

Comment: Who is your cellular provider? I wonder if they might be filtering the traffic and give lower priority to audio/video streaming traffic? So even though SpeedTest shows 30 Mbps downlink for general data, once you try to stream audio/video, they throttle it down. This sort of thing happens, unfortunately

Comment: That's a good guess because this problem started without any code change or iOS version change.  It's ATT.